# SQL Server query involving count, group by and substr

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I need this for implementing a monitoring job, I have the following question. Maybe it has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find it in my search. As I'm new here I apologize if that's the case.

I have a table, with the content of my screenshot.

I need to count these messages and group them by the type of error-message to be able to send a Report to someone. The IDs at the start of the column "fehler" are making this impossible for me and my knowledge. I would like to ignore those IDs

I hope someone could help me with this.

An example of what I need:

```
Count    | Fehler
---------+-----------------------------
  4      | Kein Content
  2      | Technical Error
530      | Signatur Server Fehler
```

If I try with this query, I only can correctly count the "Kein Content" and the "Technical Error".

The other messages are being count separately because of the unique ID, that is inside the column:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*), 
    SUBSTR(fehler, 1, 12) 
FROM
    dbo.archivierungs_fehler 
GROUP BY
    SUBSTR(fehler, 1, 12)
```

If I try with this query I only can correctly count the "Signatur Server Fehler" Messages, but the others are being count as one group with a blank message:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), 
    SUBSTR(fehler, 19, 28) 
FROM
    dbo.archivierungs_fehler 
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTR(fehler, 19, 28)
```

Thanks in advance

[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vq6d.png)

For my code I am using a program for our digital archive. It uses almost the same code as MSSQL. At the end it is translating it to TSQL. So, if I could get a code excample of how to solve this in TSQL i could try it out by directly connecting through SSMS.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? Though you do have the `dbo` schema, `SUBSTR` is not a build-in T-SQL function; it's called `SUBSTRING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to treat all of the error messages with a unique ID as a generic string:

```
DECLARE @GenericFailure nvarchar(32) = N'Signatur Server Fehler';

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT shorty = CASE 
    WHEN fehler LIKE N'%' + @GenericFailure + N'%' THEN 
      @GenericFailure 
    ELSE fehler END
  FROM dbo.archivierungs_fehler
)
SELECT shorty, COUNT(*) FROM cte GROUP BY shorty;
```

Comment: Wow Aaron, thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.